# Why cant I deselect/select JTable Boolean field reliably using Mouse

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Why cant I deselect/select JTable Boolean field reliably using a mouse, if I go into field using keyboard I can always deselect/select using spacebar. But with mouse sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.

To complicate things further the underlying data for the IS_COMPILATION boolean field is true/false but for all the other underlying fields is 1/0, the IS_COMPILATION field seems to always work okay but the others are sporadic.

Tried commenting out various bits of code without much luck. I post the JTable and TableModel subclasses here.

```
import com.jthink.songkong.text.TextLabel;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditSongsTable extends JTable
{
    public EditSongsTable()
    {
        //Disable F2 key for editing and replace with Enter character.
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.
                KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), "none");
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.
                KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "startEditing");

        //Changes Editor for Strings
        setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new TextFieldCellEditor());

        CopyAction copy   = new CopyAction(this);
        PasteAction paste = new PasteAction(this);

        //Add Copy/Paste Popup Menu
        final JPopupMenu pm = new JPopupMenu();
        pm.add(copy);
        pm.add(paste);

        //Replace default table actions with our copy/paste actions
        getActionMap().put("copy", copy);
        getActionMap().put("paste", paste);


        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                {
                    highlightCells(e);
                    doPopup(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                {
                    highlightCells(e);
                    doPopup(e);
                }
            }

            protected void doPopup(MouseEvent e)
            {
                pm.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }

            /**
             * Highlight cell if nothing selected
             *
             * @param e
             */
            protected void highlightCells(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
                if(table.getSelectedRows().length==0 || table.getSelectedColumns().length==0)
                {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();
                    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                    int col = table.columnAtPoint(point);

                    table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                    table.setColumnSelectionInterval(col, col);
                }
            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * RowNo column needs a different renderer from default
     *
     * @param row
     * @param column
     * @return the row label renderer
     */
    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
    {
        if (column == 0)
        {
            return TableRowLabelRenderer.getInstanceOf();
        }
        else
        {
            return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        }
    }


    class CopyAction extends AbstractAction
    {

        private JTable table;

        public CopyAction(JTable table)
        {
            this.table = table;
            putValue(NAME, TextLabel.COPYBUTTON.getMsg());
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            java.util.List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
            final int[] rows = getSelectedRows();
            for (int row : rows)
            {
                final int[] cols = getSelectedColumns();
                for (int col : cols)
                {
                    data.add(table.getValueAt(row, col));
                }
            }
            cb.setContents(new CellTransferable(data), null);
        }
    }

    class PasteAction extends AbstractAction
    {

        private JTable table;

        public PasteAction(JTable tbl)
        {
            putValue(NAME, TextLabel.PASTEBUTTON.getMsg());
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
            table = tbl;

            final Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

            cb.addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e)
                {
                    setEnabled(cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR)
                            || cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                }
            });
            setEnabled(cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR)
                    || cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            if (cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR))
            {
                try
                {
                    int i =0;
                    java.util.List<Object> values = (java.util.List<Object>) cb.getData(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR);
                    final int[] rows = getSelectedRows();
                    for (int row : rows)
                    {
                        final int[] cols = getSelectedColumns();
                        for (int col : cols)
                        {
                            if(i>=values.size())
                            {
                                i=0;
                            }
                            if(table.getColumnClass(col)==Boolean.class)
                            {
                                if(values.get(i) instanceof Boolean)
                                {
                                    table.setValueAt(values.get(i), row, col);
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(values.get(i) instanceof Boolean)
                                {
                                    table.setValueAt(((Boolean)values.get(i)).toString(), row, col);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    table.setValueAt(values.get(i), row, col);
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
            {
                try
                {
                    String data = (String)cb.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                    final int[] rows = getSelectedRows();
                    for (int row : rows)
                    {
                        final int[] cols = getSelectedColumns();
                        for (int col : cols)
                        {

                            table.setValueAt(data, row, col);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public static class CellTransferable implements Transferable
    {

        public static final DataFlavor CELL_DATA_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(Object.class, "application/x-cell-value");

        private Object cellValue;

        public CellTransferable(Object cellValue)
        {
            this.cellValue = cellValue;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
        {
            return new DataFlavor[]{CELL_DATA_FLAVOR};
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
        {
            return CELL_DATA_FLAVOR.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
        {
            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
            {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }
            return cellValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Table Model

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayTable;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import com.jthink.songkong.text.SongFieldDataType;
import com.jthink.songkong.text.SongFieldName;
import com.jthink.songlayer.Song;
import com.jthink.songlayer.SongFieldKey;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

import static com.jthink.songkong.analyse.toplevelanalyzer.EditSongsController.EDIT_MULTI_VALUE;

    /**
     * Edit Songs table model
     *
     */
    public class EditSongsTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
    {
        private Table<Song, SongFieldName, String> edits = null;
        private List<SongFieldName> fields;
        private List<Song>         songs;

        public EditSongsTableModel(Set<SongFieldName> fields, List<Song> songs)
        {
            super(songs.size(), fields.size());
            this.fields= new ArrayList<>(fields);
            this.songs=songs;
            edits = ArrayTable.create(songs, fields);

            for(Song song:songs)
            {
                song.setNewFilename(song.getFilename());
            }

            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
            columnNames.add("#");
            for (SongFieldName next : fields)
            {
                columnNames.add(next.getName());
            }
            this.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        }

        /**
         * Get the value relating this table field, making adjustments for certain fields for display
         *
         * @param row
         * @param column
         * @return
         */
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
        {


            if(column==0)
            {
                return String.valueOf(row + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                SongFieldName sfn = fields.get(column -1);
                Song song = songs.get(row);

                if(sfn.getSongFieldKey()== SongFieldKey.FILENAME)
                {
                    return song.getNewFilename();
                }
                else if (sfn.getDataType() == SongFieldDataType.BOOLEAN)
                {
                    if(sfn==SongFieldName.IS_COMPILATION)
                    {
                        return Boolean.valueOf(song.getFieldValueOrEmptyString(sfn.getSongFieldKey()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(song.getFieldValueOrEmptyString(sfn.getSongFieldKey()).equals("1"))
                        {
                            return Boolean.TRUE;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Boolean.FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return song.getFieldValueTripleSemiColonSeparatedOrEmptyString(sfn.getSongFieldKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object val, int row, int column)
        {
            SongFieldName sfn = fields.get(column - 1);
            Song song = songs.get(row);

            if(edits.get(song,sfn)==null)
            {
                //Save Original Value
                edits.put(song, sfn, song.getFieldValueOrEmptyString(sfn.getSongFieldKey()));
            }

            if(sfn.getSongFieldKey()== SongFieldKey.FILENAME)
            {
                song.setNewFilename((String) val);
            }
            else if(sfn.getDataType()== SongFieldDataType.BOOLEAN)
            {
                if(sfn==SongFieldName.IS_COMPILATION)
                {
                    song.setField(sfn.getSongFieldKey(), ((Boolean) val).toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    if(val==Boolean.TRUE)
                    {
                        song.setField(sfn.getSongFieldKey(), "1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        song.setField(sfn.getSongFieldKey(), "0");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                song.setField(sfn.getSongFieldKey(),
                        ((String) val).replace(EDIT_MULTI_VALUE, "\0"));
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
        {
            if(columnIndex == 0)
            {
                return String.class;
            }
            else
            {
                SongFieldName sfn = fields.get(columnIndex - 1);
                if (sfn.getDataType() == SongFieldDataType.BOOLEAN)
                {
                    return Boolean.class;
                }
                else
                {
                    return super.getColumnClass((columnIndex));
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Cannot Edit table Row Header
         *
         * @param rowIndex
         * @param columnIndex
         * @return
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            return columnIndex > 0;
        }

        /**
         * Reset to original data
         *
         * @return
         */
        public boolean reset()
        {
            for(Table.Cell<Song, SongFieldName, String> cell:edits.cellSet())
            {
                if(cell.getValue()!=null)
                {
                    SongFieldName sfn = cell.getColumnKey();
                    if(sfn.getSongFieldKey()== SongFieldKey.FILENAME)
                    {
                        cell.getRowKey().setNewFilename(cell.getValue());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.getRowKey().setField(cell.getColumnKey().getSongFieldKey(), cell.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
            fireTableDataChanged();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

TextFieldCellEditor

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;

/**
 * For String fields typing in keybaord when field has focus causes current value to be removed and editing to start
 * immediatley
 *
 */
public class TextFieldCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    private EventObject event;

    public TextFieldCellEditor()
    {
        super(new JTextField());
    }

    public final Component getTableCellEditorComponent(final JTable table, final Object val,
                                                       final boolean isSelected,
                                                       final int row, final int column)
    {
        //If entered field using keyboard clear the current value
        final JTextField editField = (JTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table,
                val,
                isSelected,
                row,
                column);
        if (event instanceof KeyEvent)
        {
            final Caret caret = editField.getCaret();
            caret.setDot(0);
            editField.setText("");
        }
        return editField;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent)
    {
        event = anEvent;
        return super.isCellEditable(anEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 classes yet no `main(String[])` method? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson why dont you try to solve the issue rather than posting that unhelpfuil comment and pushing your own work

Comment: @PaulTaylor Because people don't have time to complete your program to make it work only to test it. So, please clean your code a little bit (removing non useful third party libs, etc). Most of the time doing that will show you where the problem is. Don't rely on others to inspect your spaghetti code, make some cleaning and get back here. *Tried commenting out various bits of code without much luck.*, so you think it is a matter of chance? Andrew suggests you to post an [MCVE], most important words are **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable**.

Comment: I was hoping that it was a known problem when using checkboxes as nothing obvious in my code, looks like Im on mine own with this one then :(

Comment: I created  a SSCE but couldnt replicate the issue, then in original code I removed TableColumnAdjuster call from @camickr - https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/ and that worked, re-adding it broke code again, manually resizing column fixed it so that is the culprit but I havent worked out why it it causing an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to use of TableColumnAdjuster code from https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/ which is usually used as

```
TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
tca.adjustColumns();
```

I could not work out what the actual issue was with TableColumnAdjuster, but in the end I extracted some code from it and added it an abstract subclass of JTable that I then extend for my use case. I needed it to set sensible starting column widths only, I also adjusted to set *preferredSize* rather than *size* apart from some particular columns.

This has resolved the issue, I can now reliably disable/enable checkboxes with the mouse.

```
public class CorrectlySizedTable extends JTable
{
    public void adjustColumns()
    {
        TableColumnModel tcm = getColumnModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < tcm.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            adjustColumn(i);
        }
    }

    public void adjustColumn(final int column)
    {
        TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);

        if (! tableColumn.getResizable()) return;

        int columnHeaderWidth = getColumnHeaderWidth( column );
        int columnDataWidth   = getColumnDataWidth( column );
        int preferredWidth  = Math.max(columnHeaderWidth, columnDataWidth);

        updateTableColumn(column, preferredWidth);
    }

    /*
     *  Calculated the width based on the column name
     */
    private int getColumnHeaderWidth(int column)
    {

        TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        Object value = tableColumn.getHeaderValue();
        TableCellRenderer renderer = tableColumn.getHeaderRenderer();

        if (renderer == null)
        {
            renderer = getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(this, value, false, false, -1, column);
        return c.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    /*
     *  Calculate the width based on the widest cell renderer for the
     *  given column.
     */
    private int getColumnDataWidth(int column)
    {

        int preferredWidth = 0;
        int maxWidth = getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getMaxWidth();

        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, getCellDataWidth(row, column));

            //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

            if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
                break;
        }

        return preferredWidth;
    }

    /*
     *  Get the preferred width for the specified cell
     */
    private int getCellDataWidth(int row, int column)
    {
        //  Inovke the renderer for the cell to calculate the preferred width

        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = getCellRenderer(row, column);
        Component c = prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + getIntercellSpacing().width;

        return width;
    }

    private void updateTableColumn(int column, int width)
    {
        final TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        MainWindow.logger.severe("ColumnWidth:"+width);
        tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(width);
        if(column==0 || getColumnClass(column)==Boolean.class)
        {
            tableColumn.setMaxWidth(width);
        }
    }

    public void setModel(TableModel dataModel) {
        super.setModel(dataModel);
        adjustColumns();
    }
}
```